# Structure of the set of Linear Maps under Functional Composition

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

So I understand we can clearly form a vector space structure out of the set of linear maps with function addition, but I'm curious about what we can say about this same set with functional composition. I realize we'll have to adjust our set to essentially be two sets, the set of linear maps from *V* to *W* and then the set from *W* to *U* where *V, W,* and *U* are vector spaces. I know we don't get a vector space out of this sort of set up since composition is not commutative. So I'm just wondering what structure we have here or if we can even have a structure with two somewhat different sets. (I'm only an undergrad with background with linear algebra and intro abstract algebra to help responses level of technicality) Thanks!

Comment: Generally, one considers only the set of linear maps on a vector space $V$.

Comment: Do you know what a category is ? If you don't, do you know what an algebra is ?

Comment: Oh, I assumed you know a bit of category theory in the last paragraph of my answer since you tagged it as such.

Comment: In this case you have a bunch of sets: $L(U, V)$ and $L(V, W)$, $L(U, W)$ for example (where $U, V, W$ are vector spaces), and you have a composition operation which takes $f \in L(V, W)$ and $g \in L(U, V)$, and produces $f \circ g \in L(U, W)$. This operation is “associative” (how you parenthesise $f \circ g \circ h$ doesn’t matter). This is pretty much exactly the definition of a _category_. (You need an identity axiom as well for a category, which vector spaces do have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wuestenfux in the comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3365709/structure-of-the-set-of-linear-maps-under-functional-composition#comment6926255_3365709) is right, generally one considers the endomorphisms of a vectorspace. Let $V$ be a vectorspace, then the set of endomorphisms is $$\mathrm{End}(V) :=\{f: V \to V | f \text{ linear function}\}.$$
What structure do we have on this set? Well, we have

- the identity function $1_V$
- and function composition.

Note that composing with $1_V$ is a no-op! Also function composition is associative. Hence, we have got a **monoid** on $\mathrm{End}(V)$.

Can we have more? Perhaps a **group**? Not yet, since we cannot invert wrt. function composition. So let us consider the subset of automorphisms $$\mathrm{Aut}(V) := \{f: V \to V | f \text{ linear bijective function}\}.$$

There we also have inverses $f^{-1}$ for every $f$. (Recall that inverses of linear functions are again linear.) Indeed, we can even add two functions $f, g \in \mathrm{Aut}(V)$ implying that -- skipping some details -- we have a vectorspace structure there. So the set of all automorphisms on a vectorspace forms a vectorspace itself! And yes, you can repeat that: $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Aut}(V))$ is a vectorspace again. Have a look at [$\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{Aut}(\ldots(G)))$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5635/does-mathrmaut-mathrmaut-mathrmautg-stabilize) asking whether this process ever stabilizes. (I know, it entails math on a level higher than yours -- even mine. But I thought I link it just for you to see what one can play with.)

---

In full generality, the automorphisms $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ of an object $A$ in a category form a group! In case of the category of vector spaces, a linear function is just a morphism. A bijective linear function is an isomorphism. So you immediately see how we can express the sets above solely in categorical tonus.

---

Also if you insist on using two different sets, say the set $$\{f: V \to W | f \text{ linear function}\} \cup \{f: W \to V | f \text{ linear function}\},$$ then you get problems with function composition as the binary operation. Say you have $f, g$ from the right set, then $f \circ g$ does not make much sense. Hence, you have to make your composition operation only defined on "good" operands, or in other words, make it a partial function. That's what happens in a category. The morphism composition in a category is only defined for composable maps $A \to B$ and $B \to C$ -- *not* for, say, $A \to B$ and $C \to D$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. Definitely gave me some stuff to look up and think about further.